# GameCenter details

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on GameCenter for me. I'm building my first multiplayer app and am wondering if I will be able to grab data and create my own interface with it...

Basically I want to use my own UI to show the current games being played, if you're waiting for your turn or if it's your turn, etc with some other details from the game as well. Is this possible? Or can we only access the current games via the GameCenter UI?

Also, if I am able to skin that, or at least grab the data and skin it myself.. Is it possible to build the app around GameCenter using as little of the GameCenter UI as possible? I basically just want the user to be enclosed into my game environment instead of being thrown into GameCenter every few clicks. Make sense?

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this. The approach is to fetch all the data you need to display a UITableView with the games in progress. To show here the code for a full customized turn based gamecenter view would be to long. Maybe you get a idea of the concept if you look at the code snipped for a table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MatchCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    GKTurnBasedMatch *match = [[allMyMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.section ] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MatchCell *c = (MatchCell *)cell;
    c.match = match;
    c.delegate = self;
    if ([match.matchData length] > 0) {
        NSString *storyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[match.matchData bytes]];
        c.storyText.text = storyString;
        int days = -floor([match.creationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] / (60 * 60 * 24));
        c.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Story started %d days ago and is about %d words", days, [storyString length] / 5];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        [c.quitButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [c.quitButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

A full tutorial about that topic is in the iOS 5 by Tutorials from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial team. If you feel generous, than go ahed and follow this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-5-by-tutorials
[image: This is what you get]